# "Steam" added items that can run in the background

Tags: macos, background-process, steam, macos-ventura

I'm now on MacOS Ventura 13.1.

Recently, a pop-up window often appears on my pc.

> "Background Items Added"
> "Steam" added items that can run in the background. You can manage this in Login Items Settings.

The first time when I saw this notification, I have turned off it in my "Login Items", and the second time I uninstalled my steam. But sometimes it still pops up. Then I have searched for completely remove steam from a mac. But it doesn't work, could you please help me with this problem? Thanks so much!

Comment: Wrong forum, try https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I do have the same issue @proboba. Have you managed to fix it or started another thread? It's beyond annoying getting dozens of those notifications constantly...

Comment: Just have a look of adent’s helpful answer! Hope that works for u too^^@Wojtek

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Remove the steam .plist file in `~/Library/LaunchAgents/`.

https://www.macworld.com/article/221774/take-control-of-startup-and-login-items.html

Comment: Removing the .plist from /Users/your-username/Library/LaunchAgents worked for me. It was also suggested in your link.

Answer (score 14):

```
rm ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.valvesoftware.steamclean.plist
```

The above command works to fix this!

Comment: this command fixed the issue in macOS Ventura 13.1, ty.